# How to get the formula of Mouse Acceleration

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth, controls, hid

Before:

- I'm developing a airplay software for IOS on Windows,
- and Now I simulated a virtual mouse on windows with ble protocol
- I can click the airplay screen on windows,and iPhone can receive data messages from the virtual Bluetooth mouse

Question:
The main problem is that the **location of clicks on the computer is different from the location of responses on the mobile phone**

Description:
That is, I originally clicked the point of **(0,100)**, but the mouse on the iPhone moved to **(0,175)**, and it changed nonlinearly

Is there an acceleration algorithm for the Bluetooth mouse control of iPhone?

Comment: how to solved no-line acceletarion of mouse move